# numfmt_format_currency but without cents

Tags: php

I'm using this piece of code to format numbers from my database so it becomes currency

```
$formnum = numfmt_create( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
                    $datavalue = !empty($datavalue) ?
numfmt_format_currency($formnum, intval($datavalue), 'EUR') : '';
```

but if **$datavalue** is equal to (let say) 10, I'll get **10,00 €** 
But obviously what I wanted is **10 €**

(if you want to try it)

```
 $formnum = numfmt_create( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
 $datavalue = numfmt_format_currency($formnum,intval("10"), 'EUR');

 echo $datavalue;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, using the full scope of the NumberFormatter class (namely, the `FRACTION_DIGITS` attribute):

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$fmt->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);

echo $fmt->formatCurrency($datavalue, 'EUR');
```

Docs are here: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Comment: Thank you so much :) and in case someone wanted the procedural aproach, can you edit your post with :
$datavalue = "100";
$formnum = numfmt_create( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
numfmt_set_text_attribute($formnum, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
numfmt_set_attribute($formnum, NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
$datavalue = numfmt_format_currency($formnum, $datavalue, 'EUR');